# Error (#3502) while tring to post watch action

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

This is driving me crazy...
I am trying to use the Facebook's open graph to publish actions from my webiste to the user's wall. The verb is "watch" and the object is "video".

This is my meta tags:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="111" />
<meta property="og:type" content="video.other" /> 
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.111.com/videos.php?v=<?php echo $name;?>">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.111.com/thumbnails/<?php echo $name;?>.png">
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $caption;?>">
<meta property="og:description" content="111">
<meta property="fb:admins" content="111">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="111">
```

This is my php code:

```
//facebook
    require_once('scripts/facebook.php');
    $config = array('appId' => '111', 'secret' => '111');
    $params = array('scope'=>'publish_actions');
    $facebook = new Facebook($config);
    $user = $facebook->getUser();

    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
    $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
    if($user){

        try{
            $params = array('video'=>'http://www.111.com/videos.php?v='.$name);
            $out = $facebook->api('/me/video.watches','post',$params);
            }catch(Exception $e){
                echo $e->getMessage().'<br>';
                }
}
```

When I run the above code, I get this error:

```
(#3502) Object at URL http://www.111.com/videos.php?v=111 has og:type of 'website'. The property 'video' requires an object of og:type 'video.other'.
```

I tried using the debug tool with this url and I found no problem with it. As you can see I have `video.other` for `og:type` So it make no sence why I am getting this error. Any one know what I am doing wrong here. I already was able to publish an action to my wall using Graph API Explorer tool by facebook but not with my php code.

Comment: _“As you can see”_ – no we can’t, because you did not tell us your OG object’s real URL.

Comment: There are no errors there, the site is still under construction.

Comment: But it is publicly reachable via URL, so that Facebook’s scraper can read out the OG data?

Comment: YES, but I don't want anyone on the site yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I left stuff as it is and came back 2 hours later and every thing was working just fine.